# .Net regular expression: Inline case sensitivity not working

Tags: c#, .net, regex

What am I doing wrong here? .Net supports the (?i:) construct for inline modification of case sensitivity ... but I can't get this line to work.

```
Console.WriteLine(Regex.Match("ab(?i:z)", "abZ").Success); //Returns false, 
                                           //though it should return true??
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first parameter is the input, the second parameter is the pattern:

```
Regex.Match("abZ", "ab(?i:z)")
```

[MSDN: Regex.Match(string, string)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa332124%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

The [signature for Regex.Match](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z2heewz.aspx) is

```
public static Match Match(
    string input,
    string pattern
)
```

So, `Regex.Match("abZ", "ab(?i:z)")` will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

How about getting the parameters in the correct order?

```
Regex.Match("abZ", "ab(?i:z)").Success
```